# Добавить свой вид списка в Classic Editor

Tags: wordpress

Хочу добавить несколько списков со своими иконками для обычного Classic Editor.
В стилях нельзя менять, нужно оставить возмоность выбирать какой список использовать.

В Gutenberg эта возможность реализована. Есть хуки или фильтры куда можно обратиться? В нете нет статей, кроме как создать отдельно кнопку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант (всё можно делать в админке):

1. Добавить класс (через вкладку text в редакторе)
2. Залить картинку в Media
3. В стилях операться к классу в пункте 3, а ссылку на картинку брать из пункта 2
   нашёл в [этой статье](https://www.jezweb.info/create-custom-bullet-list-using-own-image/)